# What is an effective way to deal with iphone orientation change while displaying an image

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari

Disclaimer: I know the question of locking orientation has been asked, and solved. But that's only half my question.

I'm building an iphone website for a small indie game developer. They want to be able to show off screenshots from some of their iphone games. This is somewhat of a problem though. All the screenshots are taken from the game in landscape mode, so it really doesn't make any sense to display them in landscape.

Currently I have a very lightweight lightbox-style display for the image. You click a button on the site, and the image pops up (through ajax magic!) to occupy the full screen. Clicking anywhere on the image makes it go away, as if you had never viewed it.

I'm thinking that the two most practical solutions are either: a) lock iphone orientation for the duration of displaying the image; or b) do some very sneaky rotation on the image when the phone rotates, so no one ever notices. Are either of these possible/feasible? If so, could you give me any tips? And if not, has anyone solved a similar problem?

A demo of this is available at [my personal server](http://eqdw.net/iphone/mobile.html).

Answer (score 0):

My $.02 
As a personal design decision - I would have two images, and switch them as the rotation changes from portrait to landscape. Locking orientation seems so unfriendly. As some extra eye candy, You may want to put some sort of transition image in there between image swaps.

Here is something that may help .. http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4912

Comment: That would make sense. The problem is that the images are images *of iPhone games* (in landscape orientation). It would make no sense to have a portrait version.

Comment: I was thinking one source image that was saved twice with one copy being rotated 90 degrees.  That way you would be seeing full screen landscape either way you hold the device.